# Методы сортировки

Tags: c++builder, c++

```
int b,d,i,n,j;
int a = Memo1->Lines->Count;
int* Mas1 = new int[a];
b=a-1;

//Zdes' sortirovka massiva raznimi sposobami

for (i=0;i<=b;i++)
{
Memo1->Lines->Strings[i]=Mas1[i];
}
delete [] Mas1;
```

Уже сделал 
Метод "пузырька" max
Метод "пузырька" min
Сортировка через Strlist
С qSort разберусь потихоньку, а вот "Сортировка вставками"
"Сортировка посредством выбора", никак не получается искал в интернете информация есть, но не получается применить =((. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~harrison/Java/sorting-demo.html читали? Это примреры сотрировки, правда, на ява...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень понятно о каких Memo идёт речь. Сортировка вставками - это insertionSort(массив, число элементов в нём), а выбором - это selection(массив, левая граница, правая граница):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insertionSort(int arr[], int length) {
    int i, j, tmp;
    for (i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        j = i;
        while (j > 0 && arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
            tmp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j - 1];
            arr[j - 1] = tmp;
            j--;
        }
    }
}

void selection(int a[], int l, int r) {
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= r; j++) {
            if (a[j] < a[min])
                min = j;
        }
        if (min != i) {
            int t = a[i];
            a[i] = a[min];
            a[min] = t;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 10, *arr;
    arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

//    insertionSort(arr, n);
//    selection(arr, 0, n-1);

    printf("\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Естественно, чтобы протестировать надо раскомментировать одну из строчек.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main ()
{
  int a[10] = {3,4,1,5,6,8,8,2,4,9};
  int i, j, t;

  for (i = 8; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (j = i; j < 9; j++) {
      if (a[j] <= a[j+1])
    break;
      t=a[j]; a[j] = a[j+1]; a[j+1] = t;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf ("%d ",a[i]);
  printf ("\nEnd\n");
}
```

Это сортировка вставками по возрастанию.

Идея состоит в том, что во внутреннем цикле новый элемент вставляется **в уже упорядоченную последовательность**. На первом шаге ее длина - 1. Вставка происходит путем обмена, погружающего на каждом шаге новый элемент в уже отсортированные, пока он не займет свое место.

Внешний цикл поставляет новые элементы. Как функцию для массива размером N, думаю оформите сами.

Какой из алгоритмов называется "Сортировка посредством выбора" не помню.

Если тема интересна, советую покрутить 1). Сортировку вставками в дерево (списковая структура, упорядоченная на каждом шаге. Удобна, когда в процессе добавления неопределенного количества элементов поступают запросы на поиск) 2). Сортировку слиянием (особенно для связных списков).

Comment: Почему отсчет i начинается с 8, - 1 элемент.?

Comment: Всего 10 элементов. Индекс последнего, соответственно 9. Он уже упорядоченная последовательность из одного элемента. Перед ним элемент с индексом 8. Начинаем вставки с него, заканчиваем нулевым.

Надеюсь понятно объяснил.