# Упорядочить символы A в порядке, обратном к алфавитному c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Само задание полностью выглядит так : "через одну пустую строку предлагает ввести строку A (ввод осуществляется нажатием клавиши Enter), а затем строку В. После этого необходимо вывести обработанные строки. Если строки состоят из одних и тех же символов, то удалить из B латинские и русские буквы; в остальных случаях упорядочить символы A в порядке, обратном к алфавитному". **У меня остались проблемы лишь с упорядочиванием символов A в порядке, обратном к алфавитному c++
P.S подключение других библиотек не рассматривается**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string a,b;
    cout << "Введите строку А : ";
    getline(cin,a);
    cout << "Введите строку B : ";
    getline(cin,b);

    int j = a.size();

    char * writable = new char[a.size() + 1];

    cout << "А : " << a << endl;
    cout << "B : " << b << endl;

    const char*str1 = a.c_str();
    const char*str2 = b.c_str();
    int count1[256] = { 0 };
    int count2[256] = { 0 };
    for (const char*pos = str1;*pos;++pos)
        ++count1[(unsigned char)*pos];
    for (const char*pos = str2;*pos;++pos)
        ++count2[(unsigned char)*pos];
    bool res = true;
    for (int i = 0;i < 256;++i)
        res = res && count1[i] == count2[i];


    if (res == true) 
    {
        for (int unsigned i = 0; i < b.size();i++) 
        {
            char ch = b[i];
            if ((((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) || ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))) || (((ch >= 'а') && (ch <= 'я')) || ((ch >= 'А') && (ch <= 'Я'))))
            {
                b.erase(i, 1);
                --i;
            }

        }
        cout << "B : " << b << endl;
        res = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        /*Тут как раз не могу реализовать сортировку символов строки А в 
     обратном алфавитному порядке*/
         for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(writable) - 2;i++) 
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(writable) - 2 ;j++) 
        {
            if (writable[j] < writable[j + 1]) 
            {
                tmp = writable[j];
                writable[j] = writable[j + 1];
                writable[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
      }

        cout << "A : " << writable;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Возьмите стандартную `sort` - или это правилами игры не предусмотрено?

Comment: Нельзя использовать другие библиотеки, а sort находиться в другой библиотеке

Comment: Тогда напишите сортировку - типа сортировки вставками, пузырьком или еще какую - например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/42984/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) есть несколько готовых вариантов.

Comment: Попробывал сортировку пузырьком , но мне выводится какая-то каша по типа "ННННННННэээээ"...Что не так? Разве он не должен сравнить коды символов ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Весь ваш код:

```
std::string a,b;    
getline(std::cin,a);   
getline(std::cin,b);
// если в строке `a` не нашли символ, который нет в строке `b`
if (a.find_first_not_of(b) == std::string::npos) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < b.length(); ++i)
        //проверяем является ли символ буквой
        if(isalpha(b[i])) //функцию можете писать сами
            b.erase(i--, 1);
    std::cout << a << std::endl << b;
}
else {     //сортируем в обратном порядке
    sort(a.rbegin(), a.rend()); // функцию сортировки можете написать сами
    std::cout << a;
}
```

P.S. как сортировать последовательность, есть многочисленные способы, примеры которых вы найдете в инете и в `SO`.   И, еще: когда работаете с  `std::string`, не пытайтесь переходить на С_строку, если в этом нет необходимости. А то вы сразу  переходите работать с массивом, игнорируя преимущества и возможности `std::string`

**Пример сортировки символьной строки(если пробелы не учитывются).**
Каждый сивол помещаем в последовательность  по индексу своего `int_type` потом, начиная с конца,   присваиваем елементам исходной строки все непробелы:

```
std::string  t(255, ' ');
const size_t sz = a.length();

for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    t[+a[i]] = a[i];    // +a[i] то же, что int(a[i]) 

//теперь в t элементы распологаются в возрастающем порядке
//не считая пробелы  вытаскиваем с конца

for(size_t i = 254, j = 0;  j < sz; --i) {
    if(t[i] != ' ')
        a[j++] = t[i];
}
```

который можете написать вместо  `sort(a.rbegin(), a.rend());`